# How to upgrade a Forge provisioned Digitalocean server to php 5.6?

Tags: php5, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to upgrade the php-version from 5.5 to 5.6 on my digitalocean-boxes that I provisioned with Forge in the previous months.

Can this be done simply by executing `sudo apt-get upgrade php5`?

Comment: Why don't you spin up another instance and suck it and see ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade`

If Mongo db acts up funny, take a look at this [conversation on the laracasts forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/upgrade-a-forge-provisioned-digitalocean-server-to-php-56)